# What are the advantages/disadvantages of SQL Server bulk insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What are the advantages/disadvantages of SQL Server bulk insert?

advantages/disadvantages vs regular single row inserts while an app is processing data.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question that has no clear answer, so it may be closed. A better question would be to ask about pros and cons compared to some other specific solution.

Comment: advantages/disadvantages against what?

Comment: I've bulk inserted 20 million records in 16 minutes. It would take days to do that one record at a time from an application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the basic purpose for bulk insert is to allow for keys/constraints to be suspended while a large amount of data is imported, which would be much quicker than a conventional record-by-record/programmatic INSERT..not sure there is a "disadvantage," unless you try to use it in a scenario where it wasn't really designed/intended.

Comment: According to this blog http://richorama.github.io/2017/11/28/sql-bulk-copy/ there is an overhead in using bulk copy/insert that makes it less efficient for under 100 records but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

BCP is used for the BULK data load in sql server.Here are few advantages listed below.

1. BCP transaction is much more faster than other means
2. We can  migrate fixed length file, comma separated file using BCP
   command.
3. BCP can be used from .Net code for data migration.